# Reverse the sort order in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of products and prices that I pass to an Angular iterator. The user can select an option from a drop down that allows them to sort by one of the properties associated with the objects. When I try and reverse the order for alphabetic properties the order doesn't work.

See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pga6yaxg/

```
else if ($scope.orderBy == 'name-za') {
            return -result.name;
```

Click on the added, the price and the name a-z and these work fine, but when I choose z-a the order is incorrect. Any ideas?

Comment: Try with `return "-" + result.name;` instead.

Comment: nope. didn't work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified your **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pga6yaxg/1/)** to make it work.

Basically, I added a `reverse` variable, just like in the [AngularJS orderBy documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy):

```
<li data-ng-repeat="orderBy : [orderByOptions, recent] : reverse track by $index">
```

It works now!

**UPDATE**

By the way, you could have spared the whole filtering in the controller by just **assigning the `predicate` value to the actual value** of your `<option>` tag and simply binding the orderBy filter to the model of your `<select>`. That way you would not even use the `reverse` variable!

Check this other ***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kutyel/5wkvzbgt/)*** for the improved version.

Comment: had no effect I'm afraid. The order still has the same errors

Comment: @GrahamJRoy check edited answer, with link to corrected fiddle.